# .NET MAUI Project Creation Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

So I am currently running into problems when creating a .NET MAUI project on Windows. Whenever I try to create the project it works but as soon as I load the solution it gives me a bunch of errors. I am very new to C# so I do not know any workarounds. If you have any idea to what this might be, it would be much appreciated!

[The errors I'm running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt00C.png)

What I have tried:

- Re-installing .NET 7 as well as .NET 8 (both x86 and x64)
- Re-installing Visual Studio 2022 Community
- Running the `dotnet workload install maui-tizen` command
- Running the `dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates` command
- Debugging the problem using Chat-GPT

Comment: Have you tried `Rebuild Solution`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Hi. Yes, I have tried that, I also run into errors.

Comment: Start over. Create another new Maui project. Select .Net 7 as target platform. Build and run. If still doesn't work, delete all versions of VS (again). Reboot pc. Re-install, selecting workload that includes Maui. This time, DON'T run any `dotnet ...` commands. Try creating a new Maui project again.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This is the error I'm running into.

NETSDK1178The project depends on the following workload packs that do not exist in any of the workloads available in this installation: Microsoft.ios.Sdk.net7 Microsoft.ios.Windows.Sdk.Aliased.net7
You may need to build the project on another operating system or architecture.

Comment: It sounds like VS has gotten into a bad state. Are you running either Windows 11, or Windows 10, version 1809 or higher? If not, Maui won't work. If you are on correct Windows, run VS Installer, verify Workload / Desktop & Mobile / ".Net Multi-platform App UI development" is selected. None of the other steps you tried are needed. Delete any old projects that aren't working.

Comment: Did you try to just install the visual studio and the .net maui work load from the visual studio installer?